# How to understand SVN coming from Git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

I have been using Git for a while now. I am not a master at it but I understand many common operations. However, I just started on a project that uses subversion, and they encourage using TortoiseSVN.

I have made some costly mistakes so far and am having difficulty understanding what SVN is doing. I am looking for pointers on how to quickly get up to speed in this new environment.

What would be the most helpful piece of advice regarding understanding SVN branching and merging from a Git background?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question doesn't fit very well within the bounds of how questions should be formatted on SO... but to point you in the right direction, take a look at something like [this](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnComparison) or [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html)

Comment: Why not use [Git-SVN](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion)?

Comment: Despite the fundamental difference between distributed VCS and client-server VCS, git and SVN share a similarity in how they are used by the client machine. With git, you have your repository on the local machine (and 1 or more remotes elsewhere), to which you commit/branch/merge/etc. With SVN, there's only your working copy, with the repository that you commit/branch/merge to/from on a server or some other network location. How each VCS handles merging and revision tracking is also different, but the fundamental piece to take away when going from one to the other is the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub actually has [very concise guide](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-differences-between-svn-and-git/) for this precise purpose which I found helpful.

*Practically*, there is a difference in the relationship between branches and the directory structure. SVN branches **are actually folders in the repo**. Create another branch and the files are duplicated for you to work on (the `trunk` directory is copied into a `new-branch` directory). Git abstracts this out - the directory and its files don't change upon new branch creation.

Comment: bottom line is there is no user guide for employees who are used to git who are hired by a firm who uses SVN for some old project. even though this should be a resonably common situation. noone seems to think it's worth the effort and you link illustrates this as there is little to no usefull info therin. this question should be given a cannonical or community answer as there is no other hope for people in this situation.